# Is CPU still executing any instruction when operating system is waiting for user inputs?

Tags: linux, bash, process, operating-system

What is the CPU doing when there is only one process (like bash)  and the process is waiting for user input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the capability of the physical hardware. On typical PCs, the CPU would spend most of that time halted waiting for an interrupt to wake it up.

Comment: Thank you! One more question, is the CPU waken by itself or by another hardware when an interrupt comes?

Comment: It will be woken by whatever interrupt comes first. If nothing special happens, that will be the timer interrupt.

Comment: How could a CPU generate timer interrupt signal when it is halted? Is the timer interrupt signal generated by another chip on the motherboard?

Comment: Right. The CPU doesn't generate the timer interrupt signal, the timer (typically an [HPET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer)) does.

Comment: Well, the interrupts for mouse, KB, disk, NIC, timer etc etc. may be raised by external chips, or from peripheral subsystems within the processor package.  Either way, if the option is available in the processor instructinon set, it's normal to halt a core that has nothing to do - saves power etc.

Answer (score 1):

The CPU is (almost) never idle in a typical Linux system. If your `bash` process is halted waiting on input, the CPU will work on other processes until the blocking system call returns, signaling the `bash` process to resume.

Answer (score 0):

There is a component in practically each and every one Operating System, being it the simplest bare-bone hardware Operating System or some more advanced one like `FreeRTOS` or some desktop or server Operating System which is usually called **Scheduler**.

Scheduler is responsible for planning and distributing CPU power and for eventually switching the CPU into low-power-consumption mode which in the extreme case may mean that the CPU goes totally offline and waits for the external hardware interrupt to wake it up.

By reading about schedulers and by reading their code available from open source Operating Systems you can find out "exactly" what does the CPU usually do.

Some starting points:

- FreeRTOS - http://www.freertos.org/implementation/a00005.html
- Linux - http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c
- ReactOS - http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos/trunk/reactos/ntoskrnl/ke/thrdschd.c?revision=55247&view=markup
- MenuetOS - http://www.menuetos.net/
- OSDev.org, chapter "Scheduling" - http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page
- Google: "linux scheduler source code"